# SqlDataReader not reading data from database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to set up a login for my project, so I'm using `SqlCommand` to make the command and then I use `SqlDataReader` to read the data from the database, but whenever I try to read it the reader appears to be empty.

When I was debugging the app I noticed that the connection wasn't showing the complete version with the password, and I searched around and found out that it doesn't show it for security reasons, so I tried to use `Persist Security Info = true` but it didn't work.

Here is my connection:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=BD_GA;Uid=sa;Pwd=SQL_;Persist Security Info=True");
```

My code for the login:

```
connection.Open();
            SqlCommand commandLogin = new SqlCommand("select * from Proprietário", connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = commandLogin.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.GetValue(5).ToString() == txtUser.Text && reader.GetValue(6).ToString() == txtPass.Text)
                {
                    User = txtUser.Text;
                    tipo = reader.GetBoolean(7);
                    tssl_Login.Text = "Login feito com sucessso!";
                    break;
                }
            }
```

It should say "Login feito com sucesso" if it works but it doesn't show anything.

Comment: Try the query in SQL Server Management Studio and see if any data is returned.

Comment: `True` is missing in the connection string `Persist Security Info=`

Comment: You should use a where clause instead of returning the entire table and looping though it. And instead of returning every single column something like count(*) would be a much more efficient method. You should reference columns by name instead of ordinal position.

Comment: And you really should read about how to properly store passwords. Plain text for passwords is borderline criminal. They should be salted and hashed.

Comment: Are you sure that your table "Proprietário" has any data?

Why don't you use where in your SqlCommand?

Is a really bad practice to put user authentication info on the database. And worst without any encryption.

Comment: Why aren't you using `Initial Catalog` and `Data Source` in your connection string?

Comment: `whenever I try to read it the reader appears to be empty.`  Appears or is?  If the connection string works (it looks suspect), then stepping through the lines with the debugger will tell you if you have any data.  Avoid using the index of the columns, like `reader.GetValue(5)` and favor using the actual column name.

Answer (score 0):

Please try these details below

Connection

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source = .\\SQLEXPRESS;
Database = BD_GA;User ID = sa;Password = SQL_;Integrated Security = true;
Encrypt = False; TrustServerCertificate = True; ApplicationIntent = ReadWrite; MultiSubnetFailover = False");
```

If there is something wrong with connection it will show the error message.

```
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand commandLogin = new SqlCommand("select * from Proprietário", connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = commandLogin.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.GetValue(5).ToString() == txtUser.Text && reader.GetValue(6).ToString() == txtPass.Text)
                {
                    User = txtUser.Text;
                    tipo = reader.GetBoolean(7);
                    tssl_Login.Text = "Login feito com sucessso!";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
```